# Create persistend access to the viewer

Tags: autodesk-forge

I'm not really familiar with Autodesk's instruments, so maybe anyone could help me with Auth:

I have 2-legged auth with forge, and i need to refresh token automatically or simply make my viewer persistent.

Also any help/links/references on points of interest or  how to add floor switching feature to the project?

Answer (score 0):

Typically, when setting up the viewer, you provide a function the viewer will call whenever it needs a fresh 2-legged token. This function should make a request to your server-side logic to generate the new token. The [Learn Forge - View Your Models](https://learnforge.autodesk.io/#/tutorials/viewmodels) tutorial guides you through this process, using different languages and runtimes. For example, here's how you could implement the token updating in Node.js:

https://github.com/Autodesk-Forge/learn.forge.viewmodels/blob/nodejs/routes/oauth.js#L26-L36

https://github.com/Autodesk-Forge/learn.forge.viewmodels/blob/nodejs/public/js/ForgeViewer.js#L46-L52

Btw. a "refresh token" is only available in 3-legged auth workflows.

For features like floor switching, take a look at these:

- https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/view-each-floor-using-vertical-explode
- https://twitter.com/ipetrbroz/status/1227901732023201795

Comment: First of all, thank you for your answer)
Secondly, so in case of using 2-legged auth,i need to implement get token method, so every time user opens the viewer, it will ask fir a one-hour token?
And for ex if nobody opened my viewer, for more than one hour - token is outdated, and only if user opens the link - the new  one will be generated by Autodesk, is that right?

Comment: Glad I can help :) The viewer will automatically call the configured function when no access token is available, or when an existing token is about to expire. How that function is implemented is up to you. We typically cache the current token on the server side so that whenever one or more viewers ask for a token, we don't make unnecessary requests to Forge: https://github.com/Autodesk-Forge/learn.forge.viewmodels/blob/d4a2f4ee5a5371e6b246f8efb96cce01386caa17/routes/common/oauth.js#L33-L44.